# AST Pointer Error

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-syntax-tree

Hello i have a complete built expression tree but i think im having a problem with data-type/compatibility between pointers/nodes, i have 4 different node types:

```
class expressionNode{
private:
    expressionNode* left{nullptr};
    expressionNode* right{nullptr};
    char op{'n'};
public:
    virtual void info() const = 0;
}

class numericNode : public expressionNode
{...}

class binaryExpressionNode : public expressionNode
{...}

class functionNode : public expressionNode
{...}
```

[expr IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BugT9.jpg)

So i have that expression stored inside an std::vector of expressionNode*, i pop_back 2 items of the vector and store each one in a expressionNode*, then push_back them as one element of binaryExpressionNode*.

Finally the parser() returns all the expression of the vector (one item of expressionNode*) using

```
static_cast<binaryExpressionNode*>(v.back());
```

-**The problem is that i can only acccess the data of the root, left & right and when i try to invoke info() on all other nodes they dont display any data, are they like in invalid or undefined behavior?,**
**then it crashes. Thank you**

Comment: This sounds like a debug problem. Have you tried adding `printf` or launch a debugger?

Comment: ok im not using any debugger ill try